# Cant load jquery

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using the JavaScript SDK from facebook and I just did the what the example says to load it.This is the sample codes.

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '{{ facebook_app_id }}', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('{% if current_user %}auth.logout{% else %}auth.login{% endif %}', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FetchPic.js"></script>
</body>
```

But the problem is the all.js from facebook can be loaded successfully but neither jquery nor FecthPic can be loaded, it just keep saying  404 not found. but both of them are in the same directory as the html file. I have no idea why. Thank you

Comment: Can you load `jquery.js` using your browser's URL bar? Why not [use a CDN for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery), anyway?

Comment: What happens if you put the page's address in the browser and replace the page name with the script name?

Comment: my firebug says 404 not found and after I typed in the url in the url bar, it is blank, no result. Thank you

Comment: it is like domain/jquery.js  404 not found.

Comment: Seems, you do not have those js files in your application root.

Comment: all the html files and js files are in the same directory

Comment: there is nothing wrong with permissions I guess, it is so weird

Comment: @Clinteney Hui, then check the name of the files whether they are same or not.

Comment: 1) check if the files are corrupted 2) check if you have any redirection (`.htaccess`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

where you have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or fix the path for your local jquery instance

Answer (score 0):

Small expansion on hacknick's response:

Your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FetchPic.js"></script>
```

are telling the browser to load the scripts from the same folder as the page (HTML or whatever) that's being displayed. I imagine that's not where they are located.

Comment: they are in the same folder, which is weird.